# Linked lists and pointers confusion

Tags: c, pointers

I'm working on my final project and I was introduced to linked lists, which I must use.

I'm incredibly frustrated after trying to understand how the code works. The concept to me makes complete sense. The code i'm given as an example though, doesn't.

```
typedef struct node_s {
    char name[20]; 
    int age; 
    struct node_s *listp; 
} node;

while (!feof(inp)) {
        temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node)); // creation of memory
        fscanf(inp, "%s%d", temp->name, &temp->age);
        if (head == NULL)
            head = temp; // setting the head of the list
        else { 
            tail->listp = temp; // else connecting to previous element
        }
        tail = temp; // updating the current element
        tail->listp = NULL; // setting pointer to null.
    }
```

I'm confused at how tail->listp will point to the second element, when each time it's set to be NULL. To further illustrate my confusion, in the else statement tail->listp will point to the new element, which is understandable.

But at the end we point tail->listp to NULL which just disregard the else statement. Yet the code works just fine, and here I am, extremely confused.

Comment: The best way to understand is tracing the code with some input. You can use a debugger (e.g. gdb) for this purpose, you'll be able to see all the values at a given time. What compiler and environment (IDE, operating system) do you use?

Comment: I tried debugging using visual studio, was kind of pointless in this case to be honest. But that's surely due to my newbie skills

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the statement before, which is

```
tail = temp; // updating the current element
```

In a loop, you create a new element `temp`, and link it onto the list.  If it's the first element, you start the list by setting it to both the head and the tail, essentially.  If it's not the first element, you link it onto the end of the list.

```
tail->listp = temp;
```

Then, you set `tail=temp` to update the pointer to the end of the list, and make sure that the element at the end of the list is pointing to null

```
tail->listp = NULL;
```

You could also do

```
temp->listp = NULL;
tail=temp;
```

which would be equivalent, if my eyes don't fail me.

Comment: Oh wow, I feel silly now. The fact that tail->listp in the else statement still refer to the previous element went completely above my head. Thanks, I really appreciate your help.